# Determining what to put within the config property

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I'm a bit confused by the Sencha Touch documentation. In their [Create your first app](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.2/#!/guide/first_app) tutorial, they show a bit of code to create a panel:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Sencha',

    launch: function() {
        Ext.create("Ext.tab.Panel", {
            fullscreen: true,
            items: [
                {
                    title: 'Home',
                    iconCls: 'home',
                    html: 'Welcome'
                }
            ]
        });
    }
});
```

In the code, the `fullscreen` and `items` properties are at the base level of the json being passed in, but when you look at the [api documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.2/#!/api/Ext.tab.Panel-cfg-items) for `Ext.tab.Panel`, both properties are found under the 'Configs' section and not the 'Properties' section.

I know that there are instances where I would need to put json encoded properties in a `config` property. Like this:

```
    Ext.define('User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: [
            { name: 'id', type: 'int' },
            { name: 'name', type: 'string' }
        ]
    }
});
```

How do I determine what should go into the `config` property and what shouldn't? I'm having a hard time trying to find the explanation in the documentation.

**Additional clarification to selected Answer:**

In the first instance where we're using `Ext.create("Ext.tab.Panel",...` We're creating an instance of the Panel class. We're applying the configs directly to the instance of the Panel that will be created.

In the second instance where we're using `Ext.define('User', { extend: 'Ext.data.Model', ...`, we're *creating* a class called `User` by *extending* the class `Model`. The properties defined in the `config` property will be used to configure the `Model` class while any other properties outside of the `config` property will be used to configure the `User` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The braces are the configuration you're passing to create an instance. You're passing `fullscreen` & `items` as configurations to the tab panel. You're passing `title`, `iconCls` & `html` to the panel.

You only need to use the `config` block when defining your own classes, not instantiating them.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the clarification. That makes a lot more sense.

Comment: thanks again for your answer. It got me past a mental road block that I was stuck on. Would you say the edit that I added to my question above is accurate as far as fully explaining the concept?